# Is it possible to set a theme with plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly, themes

```
plot_ly(x,y,z, type="scatter3d") + theme_igray()
```

Returns NULL. Is it possible at all to have theme with plotly?

Answer (score 2):

The `theme_igray()` call looks like something from `ggplot2`.  I don't think the `plotly` package supports `ggplot2` themes, but `ggplotly` can convert a `ggplot2` graph to `plotly` format, so you could theme it in `ggplot2` then convert.

Unfortunately, there's no `ggplot2` graph that corresponds to `type="scatter3d"`.  The `gg3D` package will produce a 2D graph in `plotly`.

Comment: Thanks. Can ggplotly convert a plotly plot?

Comment: I don't think so.